# check data exist or not before inserting using curl?

Tags: php

I want to insert data into an active-campaign. Before that, I want to check if the data is existing or not in the active campaign.

```
function syncContact($data)
{
    $contact = [
        'u' => 7,
        'f' => 7,
        's' => null,
        'c' => 0,
        'm' => 0,
        'act' => 'sub',
        'v' => 2,
        // Form fields
        'field[1]' => $data['field[1]'], // For gender field
        'fullname' => $data['firstName'] .' ' . $data['lastName'], // Firstname + lastname
        'email' => $data['email'],  // For email field,
        'field[7]' => $data['field[7]'], // For datum,
        'field[15]' => $data['field[15]'], // For ChatVerlauf
        'field[14]' => $data['field[14]'], // For ChatTag
        'field[16]' => $data['field[16]'], // For ChatURL
        'field[17]' => $data['field[17]'], // For ChatInteresse
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://.......");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contact);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

}

```
if($data) {
            $data['email'] = $data[3];
            $data['firstName'] = $data[5];
            $data['lastName'] = $data[6];
            $data['field[1]'] = $data[4];
            $data['field[7]'] = $data[1];
            $data['field[15]'] = $data[7];
            $data['field[14]'] = $data[2];
            $data['field[16]'] = $data[9];
            $data['field[17]'] = $data[10];

            $this->syncContact($data);
        }
```

Insertion is working perfectly. But before that, I want to check the data is exists or not and if not exist insert.

Comment: It's kind-of unclear what you mean. In general, I'd say just get hold of the active campain and check whether the data exists there. This may be prone to race conditions when it's not done properly, but should be feasible. However, there's also the `$data` variable, did you want to check a property of that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your code. I would say you can use try catch block with the help of Exception you will get the exception code. You can return the exception code via curl response. 
On sql/mysql table Please make combination of primary key appropriately.

```
try{
if($data) {
        $data['email'] = $data[3];
        $data['firstName'] = $data[5];
        $data['lastName'] = $data[6];
        $data['field[1]'] = $data[4];
        $data['field[7]'] = $data[1];
        $data['field[15]'] = $data[7];
        $data['field[14]'] = $data[2];
        $data['field[16]'] = $data[9];
        $data['field[17]'] = $data[10];

        $this->syncContact($data);
 }
    }catch(\Excetion $e){
    return $e->getCode();
}
```

Comment: $pramod. I add the same code, but I got HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @AnjuGopi Please check it again. I have made a slight change in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to check for an empty array or object.

```
if(isset($data) && count($data) != 0){
  // your insert code...
}
else{
  // your message that data is empty...
}
```

**Note:** As @Pramod's code describes using try... catch block is also well and good but just check if your variable is empty or not first because an empty array will have '[]'.

Comment: $data is an array of data that I need to insert to the active campaign. My doubt is how could I check if the $data value not in the active campaign or not.

Comment: @AnjuGopi Sorry but I didn't understand what you are trying to say in the above statement. "My doubt is how could I check if the $data value not in the active campaign or not."